# @angular/material styles in a single stylesheet

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to move all the styles into a single stylesheet, no individual component styles. I can control my styles, however when I include @angular/material components, they are added as individual style tags:

[image: Renders]

I have a single styles.scss file, which already includes the material designs according to the [docu](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

```
// Include the default theme styles.
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

How can I also add all the components into the single stylesheet?

Edit: this is how the `@angular/material` modules are added:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Comment: this sounds like [@import](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_import_rule.asp) ?

Comment: Yes, the styles are imported via '@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);' which should add all components to the stylesheet. However the styles are still done via adding style tags

Comment: Besides global styles material also uses local styles through `styleUrls` like https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/39888f373967149264ecd729824a33d25db19d6f/src/lib/button/button.ts#L77 So they are added as inline styles

Comment: Can I change that`?

Comment: @Mike http://take.ms/IWhoM

Comment: @mike yes, this should be done with include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme); accodring to the documentation.yurzi already took a look at your linke and as far as I can tell this is more for theming...

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7219#issuecomment-319610306

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to the `angular-material-theme()` mixin will include theming only for components plus core (global) styles. Angular Material component style that is not part of theming is encapsulated and built in to the component and dynamically added to the DOM. There is no way to automatically include those styles in a single stylesheet. Even if you could do that, it is possible that everything might not work properly, plus you would also need to turn off the style tags inserted into the DOM by the components, which isn't possible. Furthermore, since the components themselves already contain the style code, you would be adding a lot of size to the page by duplicating the style in a global stylesheet. In other words, you can't do it and it shouldn't be done.

Comment: @VictorK - I don't see how any of those workarounds would give you a 'single stylesheet' solution that the OP is after. Plus, there would probably still be issues because Angular material sometimes uses the style attribute on elements and does animations via javascript. Those things aren't addressed by your 'solutions' - and probably can't be - as far as I can see. The real problem is that Angular Material is not designed as a css style library, and not intended to be used or customized that way. A fair bit can be accomplished with hacks, but if it needs that much hacking, why use it at all?